# Highcharts Renderer Button ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've rendered the `buttons` to multiple `Highcharts`, but I need to know which `button` I click.. 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/kh5jY/9510/)
[API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.button)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside a callback `this` refers to the clicked button. You can also set its id if you use `attr()` method.

```
var custombutton = charts[i].renderer.button('button', 450, 10, function() {
  // not working
  alert(this.element.id);
}, null, hoverState, pressedState).attr({
  id: 'button-' + i
}).add();
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/kh5jY/9517/

Comment: This is a nice way